# TensorDataset gives error 'int' object is not callable, but all inputs are numpy arrays

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm working on translating a TensorFlow project to PyTorch, but I've run into a strange error. When I try to create a `TensorDataset` like this

```
train_data = TensorDataset(
    self.x_train[idx_train], 
    self.covariates_train[idx_train],
    self.y_train[idx_train]
)
```

torch throws `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`. The corresponding TensorFlow code works. I also checked the inputs, and they are all of the correct shape. Specifically, each argument is of the following shape:

```
Argument 1:  (200, 1, 40, 26) (180,) (180, 1, 40, 26)
Argument 2:  (200, 2) (180, 2)
Argument 3:  (200, 51) (180, 51)
```

These shapes match the corresponding TensorFlow code at the analogous point in the code (i.e., when I'm about to feed these same inputs into `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`).

Comment: The only thing being called in that line of code is `TensorDataset`.  Have you perhaps assigned an integer to that name?

Comment: No, that was the first thing I checked, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast the inputs to `torch.Tensor` when using `torch.utils.data.TensorDataset`:

```py
import torch
import numpy as np

x_train = np.random.uniform(size=(200, 1, 40, 26))
y_train = np.random.uniform(size=(200, 51))

dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(
    torch.from_numpy(x_train),
    torch.from_numpy(y_train)
)
```

That's not required with `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` which supports different data types in addition to `tf.Tensor`.